# Java IO. Как получить из BufferedInputStream сам буфер?

Tags: java, io

Помогите разобраться я использую `BufferedInputStream`:

```
    try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(path), 1024)) { // указал размер буфера 1024
        // я хочу прочитать из файла сразу много байт 
        //иначе зачем мне был бы нужен буфер...
        byte[] buffer = in. // и тут я столкнулся что все методы возвращают int
```

Так как же мне из `BufferedInputStream` получить сам массив байт
размером 1024 ради которого я создавал эту обертку? Что я не так делаю?

**Дополнение к вопросу:**

Я делаю:

```
try (BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(path), 1024)) {

            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            int data = in.read(bytes,0,1024);
            while (data != -1) {
                sb.append(new String(bytes, "UTF8")); //StringBuilder
                data = in.read();
            }
            System.out.println(sb);
```

1. И после вывода строки еще куча квадратов ... как мне понять что последняя часть файла уже не содержит такой длинны?
2. Я пишу в конструкторе `BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path), 1024)` 1024 - это размер буфера как я понимаю, но и при создании массива `new byte[1024]` я так-же указываю длину вроде тоже размер буфера. В чем разница?

Comment: Что не работает? Какой результат вы ожидаете и какой получаете?

Comment: Я ожидаю что при чтении  большого файла я смогу использовать большой буфер, но когда файл подойдет к концу в нем останется прочитать еще немного и это не много будет меньше чем буфер то я смогу дописать этот остаток не получая негативного эффекта от чтения null которые останутся в конце массива-буфера, потому что когда я использую != -1 то у меня в конце строки которая получается при чтении выходят еще какие-то квадраты я я так понимаю и есть эти нули которые оказались не заполненными.

Comment: Ладно я лучше это удалю и другой вопрос создам вы правы так бордак получается...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Методы возвращают количество прочитанных байт. Читать надо так

```
 count = in.read(buffer, <с какого места заполнять массив>, <сколько байт прочиать>)
```

В `count` будет количество прочитанных байтов. Байты попадут в массив `buffer`. Если случиться конец файла, то `read` вернет -1.

Размер буфера для потока указывается в конструкторе потока. По умолчанию размер буфера

```
 private static int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 8192;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое вам за ответ, не могли бы уточнить для меня еще пару моментов. Я дополнил ими вопрос. По поводу как понять что мы дошли до конца файла. И этот конец вряд ли будет содержать точно такое число байтов которое мы указали для буфера. И второй по поводу где на самом деле указан размер буфера, в длине массива или в конструкторе BufferedInputStream?

Comment: количество прочитанных байтов вернет `read`. если случился конец файла, то будет -1. размер буфера для потока указывается в конструкторе потока.

Comment: Ага с остатком в потоке разобрался, спасибо. А по поводу размера буфера если я ничего не указываю в конструкторе то все работает точно так-же. Зачем нужна перегрузка с размером буфера? Вряд-ли это шутка от товарища Блоха?

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Все теперь кажется я понял. Но все таки есть еще один не большой но существенный момент, - обновил вопрос.

Comment: Прочтите правила использования SO. Вы их активно нарушаете изменяя вопрос после ответа.